# How to create a HUGE rumbly kick drum?

Tags: reverb, kick

I'm looking to create a deep rumbly kick drum like in these tracks:

I love these tight reverb kicks, that when the highpass lets off, the rumble is awesome.

I get the impression that this kick drum may be layered with a ton of compression and a send reverb, but every time I try I can't get anything close to it.  Most other kicks in dance music I can get very close to... These I'm stumped!

I've tried: pitching down percussion and adding a "top kick" on top with EQ and Compression and sending to reverb.... Every time I end up with something really muddy.

Please help!  This is exactly the style I'm leaning towards, and have always loved.  Any other tips on creating clean bass heavy music like this would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try clean 909(first)/808(second) Kicks and tune them to around 45 Hz. Then use gates reverb if you want but really be careful with the amount ant eq setting on the reverb channel. Also fine-tune the pre delay a good amount of time.

Then something that i think he used is parallel compression with some distortion. This can help you make the reverb tail rumble. Set up a send where you compress the kick+ reverb heavily. Its important that no transient is coming trough. Then use short attack/release times to distort the signal or use a distortion plugin afterwards. Then feed this back.

Also try Ringshifters on the kick and bit crushing kick + reverb to get the grit (could be you tubes compression so)

Peace

Edit: The bass of the kick comes from the sub bass synth imho